# React useState hook only updates once onClick

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to toggle true/false in my component using useState but I've noticed it only toggles one time and does not go back and forth. On clicking the component, it toggles `true` but then it won't toggle back to `false`. Any ideas on how to solve?

```
const [sound, setSound] = useState(false);

return (
    <div>
    <ReactPlayer
         ...
         muted={sound}
         onClick={() => {
             setSound(!sound);
             console.log("on click", sound);
         }}
     />
     </div>
)
```

**EDIT**
Thanks for the replies, I think the issue was the anon function, I solved it by doing this

```
         onClick={() => {
             setSound((sound) => !sound);
             console.log("on click", sound);
         }}
```

Comment: Can you please show more code in your component?

Comment: @sn4ke updated the answer - do check if it is useful

Comment: @Codenewbie not sure if it works differently with a youtube or local file (my case) but this solved it `setSound((sound) => !sound);` -- it might also be different when the onClick is happening on the video instead of a button

Answer (score 0):

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import './App.css';

const ReactPlayer = ({muted, onClick}: {muted: boolean, onClick: () => any}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={onClick}>Test</button>
      <p>{muted.toString()}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

function App() {
  const [sound, setSound] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="App">
        <ReactPlayer
        muted={sound}
        onClick={() => {
        setSound(!sound);
        console.log("on click", sound);
      }}
        />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This code works perfectly, I don't know what you have in your ReactPlayer component, but this should work

Answer (score 0):

> As of Chrome 66, videos must be muted in order to play automatically. Some players, like Facebook, cannot be unmuted until the user interacts with the video, so you may want to enable controls to allow users to unmute videos themselves. Please set muted={true}. [see docs for more info](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-player)

[Check the live code here in sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/still-frog-lon63?file=/src/App.js)

```
import ReactPlayer from "react-player";
import React, { useState } from "react";

// Render a YouTube video player

export default function App() {
  const [play, setPlay] = useState(true);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ReactPlayer
        muted={play}
        url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9DDX3US3kss"
      />
      Click to Mute or Unmute --
      <button style={{ margin: "15px" }} onClick={() => setPlay(!play)}>
        Mute/UnMute
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```